# Cannot read property 'style' of null when using my ChangeColor function on onmouseover

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying onmouseover for the first time and I keep getting the error when my function executes.  What am I missing?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
> at ChangeColor (index.html:55)
> at HTMLDivElement.onmouseover (index.html:42)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tim Neufeld - Home</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                background-color: gray;
            }
            .titlebar {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;

            }
            .titlebar-name {
                text-align: right;
                position: fixed;
                top: 2px;
                right:0px;
                color: lightblue;
                font-size: 250%;
                width: 240px;
            }
            .leftLinkBar {
                position: fixed;
                top: 50px;
                height: 5000px;
                width: 200px;
                background-color: rgb(121, 0, 0);
                color: #B83DBC;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="titlebar">
            <div onmouseover="ChangeColor()" class="titlebar-name">Tim Neufeld</div>     
        </div>
        <div class="leftLinkBar">
            testing
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ChangeColor() {
                var cArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,"A","B","C","D","E","F"];
                var c = "#";
                for (i=0; i < 6; i++) {
                    c = c + cArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
                }
                console.log(c);
                document.getElementById("titlebar-name").style.color = c;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using getElementById, but you don't have any element with this id, only element with this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an `id` to the element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tim Neufeld - Home</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                background-color: gray;
            }
            .titlebar {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;

            }
            .titlebar-name {
                text-align: right;
                position: fixed;
                top: 2px;
                right:0px;
                color: lightblue;
                font-size: 250%;
                width: 240px;
            }
            .leftLinkBar {
                position: fixed;
                top: 50px;
                height: 5000px;
                width: 200px;
                background-color: rgb(121, 0, 0);
                color: #B83DBC;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="titlebar">
            <div onmouseover="ChangeColor()" class="titlebar-name" id="titlebar-name">Tim Neufeld</div>     
        </div>
        <div class="leftLinkBar">
            testing
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ChangeColor() {
                var cArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,"A","B","C","D","E","F"];
                var c = "#";
                for (i=0; i < 6; i++) {
                    c = c + cArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
                }
                console.log(c);
                document.getElementById("titlebar-name").style.color = c;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course.  I am not sure how I missed that.  Thank you.

Comment: @TimNeufeld you are welcome. Please mark the answer as the solution.